# Magento 2 : Change email content based on shipping method in email template

Tags: magento2, email-templates

I need to change the email content based on shipping method. there are two type of shipping method one is in store pickup and one is delivery to user location.

For both case content of email template is like :

```
Thank you for your order from XYZ. Once your package ships we will send you a tracking number. You can check the status of your order by logging into your account.
```

I don't want this line "Once your package ships we will send you a tracking number." for in store pickup and change this line with some other info.

My Email template sample like :

```
{{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}

<table>
    <tr class="email-intro">
        <td>
            <p class="greeting">{{trans "%customer_name," customer_name=$order_data.customer_name}}</p>
            <p>
                {{trans "Thank you for your order from %store_name." store_name=$store.frontend_name}}
{{trans "Once your package ships we will send you a tracking number."}}
                {{trans 'You can check the status of your order by <a href="%account_url">logging into your account</a>.' account_url=$this.getUrl($store,'customer/account/',[_nosid:1]) |raw}}
            </p>
            <p>
                {{trans 'If you have questions about your order, you can email us at <a href="mailto:%store_email">%store_email</a>' store_email=$store_email |raw}}{{depend store_phone}} {{trans 'or call us at <a href="tel:%store_phone">%store_phone</a>' store_phone=$store_phone |raw}}{{/depend}}.
                {{depend store_hours}}
                    {{trans 'Our hours are <span class="no-link">%store_hours</span>.' store_hours=$store_hours |raw}}
                {{/depend}}
            </p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="email-summary">
        <td>
            <h1>{{trans 'Your Order <span class="no-link">#%increment_id</span>' increment_id=$order.increment_id |raw}}</h1>
            <p>{{trans 'Placed on <span class="no-link">%created_at</span>' created_at=$created_at_formatted |raw}}</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="email-information">
        <td>
            {{depend order_data.email_customer_note}}
            <table class="message-info">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        {{var order_data.email_customer_note|escape|nl2br}}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            {{/depend}}
            <table class="order-details">
                <tr>
                    <td class="address-details">
                        <h3>{{trans "Billing Info"}}</h3>
                        <p>{{var formattedBillingAddress|raw}}</p>
                    </td>
                    {{depend order_data.is_not_virtual}}
                    <td class="address-details">
                        <h3>{{trans "Shipping Info"}}</h3>
                        <p>{{var formattedShippingAddress|raw}}</p>
                    </td>
                    {{/depend}}
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="method-info">
                        <h3>{{trans "Payment Method"}}</h3>
                        {{var payment_html|raw}}
                    </td>
                    {{depend order_data.is_not_virtual}}
                    <td class="method-info">
                        <h3>{{trans "Shipping Method"}}</h3>
                        <p>{{var order.shipping_description}}</p>
                        {{if shipping_msg}}
                        <p>{{var shipping_msg}}</p>
                        {{/if}}
                    </td>
                    {{/depend}}
                </tr>
            </table>
            {{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order_id=$order_id area="frontend"}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

{{template config_path="design/email/footer_template"}}
```

I see the email for **In store Pickup**

{{var order.shipping_description}}

value is like "In-Store Pickup Delivery - "
And For Second One Value is like "Flat Rate - Fixed".

Please help like which condition i need to put for the content changes.

Thanks

Comment: There is actually no way to achieve the behaviour you want in your template with {{ depend }} and {{ if }} statements. The easiest way to achieve this is to extend your order parameters and load a block element instead of just translation.

Comment: I don't know much about magento 2, Can you help me like what i need to change?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by adding your logic to an observer.

Create basic module

registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_Module',
    __DIR__
);
```

module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
         <module name="Vendor_Module" setup_version="1.0.0"/>
    </config>
```

Register an observer for when email templates are loaded

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">    
                <event name="email_order_set_template_vars_before">
            <observer name="name_of_observer" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\AddVariable" />
        </event>
    </config>
```

In your Observer  app\code\Vendor\Module\Observer\AddVariable.php

```
<?php
    namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;
    use Magento\Sales\Model\Order;
    use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
    class AddVariable implements ObserverInterface
    {
        protected $order;
        public function __construct(
            Order $order
        ) {
            $this->order= $order;
        }
        public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
        {
            /** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action $controller */
            $transport = $observer->getEvent()->getTransport();
            if($transport->getOrder() != null)
            {
                $order = $this->order->load($transport->getOrder()->getId());
                $shipping_method = $order->getShippingAddress()->getShippingMethod();
                $transport['variable'] = /*some logic ... */
                
            }
        }
    }
```

`$transport['variable']` adds the variable to your data. You can call it like any other variable from your template and assign as many as you like.